# htaccess - Redirect unless any query

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting most pages, including the index, from firstdomain.com to seconddomain.com.

To redirect the pages, I use:

```
Redirect 301 /faq http://www.seconddomain.com/faq
Redirect 301 /contact http://www.seconddomain.com/contact
```

To redirect the index, I use:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.seconddomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Now, the problem is that I want http://www.firstdomain.com/?query=9328 to remain. With the above code it redirects to http://www.seconddomain.com/?query=9328

My question is: How do I redirect the index unless it contains a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.seconddomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

I have no idea if it's the correct or best way, but it does redirect the index unless it's followed by a query string.

Comment: Except that it doesn't answer your original question ;-?  This only redirects if the query parameters are omitted entirely, which is not what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix the `RewriteRule` with a `RewriteCond`using a Negative lookahead on the query string, for example

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?!query=9328)
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.seconddomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

This will skip the redirect if the query string contains the pattern.  If you have valid query parameters such as `otherquery`, etc. then you might want to anchor the pattern with `\b` bookends.

Comment: Thank you! 
A couple of issues: When I'm testing this code on the online htaccess tester htaccess.mwl.be the output is `seconddomain.com/?query=9328`.
Also, I do not want to be redirected if there is ANY query present in the URL.